# Setting RESULT_CANCELED in widget configuration activity redundant?

Tags: android, android-activity, widget

I am wondering about the following.
In the Android documentation they recommend the following:

"Tip: When your configuration Activity first opens, set the Activity result to RESULT_CANCELED, along with EXTRA_APPWIDGET_ID, as shown in step 5 above. This way, if the user backs-out of the Activity before reaching the end, the App Widget host is notified that the configuration was cancelled and the App Widget will not be added."

https://developer.android.com/guide/topics/appwidgets/index.html#Configuring

But isn't that redundant, since the default value is RESULT_CANCELED (0) anways? Am I missing something? Can there be cases where the result is not at 0 when we open the configuration activity?

Comment: It's not so much that the result code needs to be set. It's the result `Intent` that's important. It needs to have the Widget ID attached, or [bad things can happen](https://stackoverflow.com/q/40708973).

Comment: Oh of course, how could I miss that. Makes total sense! You can add this as an answer as well.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The important part of that statement is "along with EXTRA_APPWIDGET_ID". You're correct that the result code will be `RESULT_CANCELED` by default, but there isn't going to be a result `Intent` with the Widget ID attached by default.

Certainly, any launcher that allows Widgets should be able to handle it gracefully if that `Intent` is not set, but it's a known issue that at least [some do not](https://stackoverflow.com/q/40708973).

Comment: Thank you. Right now I check for the app widget id and finish the activity if it should be "INVALID_APPWIDGET_ID". So I should set my result value before this part? Or wont the result have any benefit if it doesnt contain a valid ID?

Comment: I'm not sure if I understand what you're asking. You should set the `RESULT_CANCELED` code and its `Intent` with the incoming Widget ID in `onCreate()`, so if the user backs out, it's already set.

Comment: Oh, yeah, always use the ID you get passed to you.

Comment: What I mean is, what if the appWidgetId I get from getIntent is invalid? Will the launcher still choke if I pass this in the result intent?

Comment: It really shouldn't, _if_ it passed that to you. I wouldn't think it ever would, though, unless something's gone horribly wrong on its end.

Comment: So it would still make sense to set the result intent with the invalid id, before potentially finishing the activity (because of the invalid id)?

Comment: Yeah, basically. I mean, there's nothing else you can do about it. You don't really have any control over ID generation or assignment, so all you can do is pass back whatever you get.

Comment: Yea, makes sense

Comment: I just want to say thank you again because you have been a great help for me today.

Comment: No problem. Glad to help. Good luck with your project. Cheers!